# Why "bundle update" doesn't update the Gemfile to use Rails 3.0.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I tried using `bundle update` for a Rails 3.0.0 project I created, expecting all the content in `Gemfile` (and also `Gemfile.lock`) to reflect rails 3.0.5...

But it keep on being 3.0.0...  even if I run `bundle update rails`, it still keep on being 3.0.0

Out of curiosity, I created a brand new Rails 3.0.0 project, and then run bundle update on it... and it still says "using rails 3.0.0", why?  And how to make `bundle update` update to 3.0.5?  (other than the obvious way to change the Gemfile by hand)

(I even tried changing `sqlite3-ruby` to `sqlite3` in the `Gemfile`, because 3.0.5 seems to use `sqlite3` instead.  And `rails` and `sqlite3` are the only 2 gems listed in `Gemfile`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You already had the answer: change the gem version by hand and run `bundle update rails`.

I suspect you have `gem 'rails', '3.0.0'` in your Gemfile. Running `bundle update rails` won't change the version if you have the exact version specified.

Here's some info about the different ways of specifying gem versions in your Gemfile.

http://gembundler.com/rationale.html

Comment: so I guess your answer is, `'3.0.0'` in Gemfile means use exact version.  If I want it to update to the newest whenever `bundle update` is used, then use `> 3.0.0`, although I don't know if this is recommended or not, but sure keeps project using the newest rails.

Answer (score 15):

Yeah you probably have

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
```

change it to

```
gem 'rails', '~>3.0.0'
```

This will only upgrade minor versions of rails(3.0.5 & 3.0.6 ...).  Or you can change it to

```
gem 'rails', '~>3.0'
```

if you want to upgrade to rails 3.1 but not 4.0

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the top result when searching for "bundler wont update" on Google so I'm adding following as another answer. I was facing this issue in one of my projects.

In one of my projects I had a `.bundle/config` file which had following line:

```
BUNDLE_FROZEN: "1"
```

This was causing `bundle update <gemname>` to have no effect. I removed above line and it started updating again.

Comment: you are right, that could be one of the possibility.